# Embedding a Google Chrome App into a web page for us in another browser

Tags: google-chrome, embed, html, google-chrome-app

We have an test app in the Google Chrome Web Store to try and combat the upcoming demise of Java.

We had to go via the Google Web Store as our app required sockets. However, we need to embed this in our product, which uses the browser.

**Is there a way to embed a Google Web App in another web page?**

Answer (score 0):

Use the [appview](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/appview) tag to embed other Chrome Apps within your Chrome App. No other ways to embed the Chrome Apps. 
Read about [Chrome Apps Architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_architecture).

Also read about [Native Client](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client). Maybe that is your way.

Comment: Hi, the issue we're facing is we need to use sockets BUT we can't use an official Chrome App as we need to embed our application in our own product, which uses a browser interface. (Discontinuance of Java is the reason for our dilemma as we need a replacement "applet" for chrome users).

Comment: It would be good to look at your product for better understanding. Can you use [HTML5 WebSockets](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets)?